# Fix line between head and body

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, objects

I'm completely new to blender. My problem is as follows :

1 - I downloaded two 3D XPS models from two excellent artists.

2 - I imported my two models into Blender.

3 - I removed all the bones and vertices from the first model, leaving only its head.

4 - I then removed the head and head bones from my second model.

5 - I moved the head of my first model to the body of my second model.

6 - I edited the necks of my two models so that my two meshes match.

I've ended up with a too obvious dividing line between the two mesh parts :

[image]

Even with two of the same materials, the line is very apparent:

[image]

Even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join the two meshes doesn't make this line disappear

[image]

In another post, someone had the same problem as me.

I tried the proposed solutions but without success.

I also want to join the two armatures to get one model with his bones already set ect...

But I don't really know how to do that. When i select the two armatures in object mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> the head mesh is changing position.

[Blender Work RAR](https://mega.nz/file/mgQXEZQK#AAwxvyxxbJYOA3ycSEvyzVDKN7_9NAgCkkfBvepGWvk)

**EDIT 12/10/23 :**

I did what moonboot said and here are the results :

With a simple color material as example the line have almost disapeared :

[image]

But in the back of the neck the line's still here :

[image]

Here is my simple example color material settings :

[image]

**LATEST EDIT 12/10/23 9:34 P.M**

here is what happened by making a copy of my original files and then open the copied files :

[image]

Comment: Booba ( ͡~ ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the head to the body object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to remove overlapping vertices. <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Shade Smooth* again in *Object* mode. The head skin and the body skin don't have the same material, give them the same material and you won't see the limit. Also they don't have the same *Viewport Display* color, that's why we still see a difference when we are in *Solid* preview mode.

Comment: Hi there @moonboots ! Thanks for your quick answer ! I have join the two mesh (ctrl + J) and I did all you said after. (merge by distance and shade smooth) I give the new mesh part a material. So it's the same on the two joined parts now. I went to the material viewport display and changed all settings to be the same on every of my projects materials. I don't know how to make you see my screenshots here... Do I have to "answer my question" ?

Comment: You can edit your original post and add an image. Does my solution work or do you still have some problems?

Comment: Hi again ! I added the pic to show what happenned !

Comment: I'll come back here this evening because I have to go work ! See you later moonboots !

Comment: it seems like it has to do with the bump and/or normal map you're using but you haven't shared the images and the setup seems pretty complicated, if you don't need any bump or normal map you could simply unplug them

Comment: Hi I'm back ! I just use a color material as an example ! There's no bump or normal map ! I edited my post with a pic !

Comment: And there is also a download link to my backup project before the modifications so you can have a look of what's happening !

Comment: Check your material, you've plugged some Bump and Normal maps into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF, unplug to see what it gives

Comment: ehm.... I don't think I plugged something in the normal input of BSDF node on the last pic.......

Comment: ok, could you please share your latest file?

Comment: My project files in the download link aren't the modified files. But the pictures I take are from my copied files where I do some modifications according to what you are telling me to do ! I just wanted to precise that just in case if you have downloaded my project files ! Besides, I give you the permission to edit and check my files. Perhaps you can understand better the problem by looking at my project directly into blender...

Comment: oh wait. I'll share the latest.

Comment: WAIT Moonbooooooooooot !!!!!!!!!!!!! I made a backup of my project files to pack them for you. So, I made a copy of my original blender project files and open it again to see if It was the good files and if textures were missing etc AND in the copied file THE LINE HAVE DISAPEARED !!!!!!!!!!!! YEEES !!!!!! I edit my post to send you a screenshot !!!! Maybe it was a blender bug...

Comment: mmh ok not sure what happened   ;)

Comment: Post edited ! That's the last pic ! I don't understand what happened but it is now solved... XD Thank you for taking the time to help a poor newbie like me moonboot !

Comment: OK great, you're welcome  ;)